# How to check any of many elements exists on a page in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, puppeteer

In our web-**scraping** project,
we expect problems if any one of these elements occur,
we did in this way but i think there should be a better way

```
await page.waitForTimeout(() => document.querySelectorAll(`div.ui-dialog-content.ui-widget-content.ui-draggable,
#ngiForm > div.fieldcontainer.user-code.pt10 > div.error-wrapper > div,
#passwordFC > div.error-wrapper > div,
#otpPasswordLabel,
div.modal-header.error > h1,
.repush
`).length);
```

If any of elements occur length becomes 1,
How can we improve this?

We're trying to, go in a loginpage, wait until page loads, and if any of given elements occurs on page that means, either a popup or another problem is there

Comment: The issue isn't clear. From the user of `waitForTimeout()` I assume you're waiting for the DOM to load and these elements to be populated? If so, use a MutationObserver, or possibly an AJAX promise/callback if that's the source of these elements. If that's not what you're doing, please add detail to the question about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: why wait for timeout?

Comment: we are trying to, go in a loginpage, wait until page loads, and if any of given elements occurs on page that means, either a popup or another problem is there

Comment: It sounds like this works exactly as described. What exactly are you looking to improve?

Comment: What sort of "improvement" are you looking for?  "*if any of elements occur length becomes 1*"- would it not become the length of the items found?  ie 1 or more.

Comment: Just use a normal selector, `page.$`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting all DOM items, you can select one by one, checking the presence.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.ui-dialog-content.ui-widget-content.ui-draggable').length
|| document.querySelectorAll('#ngiForm > div.fieldcontainer.user-code.pt10 > div.error-wrapper > div').length
|| document.querySelectorAll('#passwordFC > div.error-wrapper > div').length
|| document.querySelectorAll('#otpPasswordLabel').length
|| document.querySelectorAll('div.modal-header.error > h1').length
|| document.querySelectorAll('.repush').length
```

If one item is found, next aren't searched.
And you may order `document.querySelectorAll` by probability of presence on the page.

Comment: You can also order by speed of selection, eg `#id` will be much quicker than `.class > node` (over many iterations) - but perhaps this is a micro-optimisation